# Is there a measure similar to the Helstrom measurement which can distinguish between more than 2 pure quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-states

My understanding is the Helstrom measurement distinguishes between 2 pure quantum states.

Is there a measure similar to the Helstrom measurement which can distinguishes between more than 2 pure quantum states? Or can the Helstrom measurement be generalized to do this?